# Laurent Series Expansion: $(e^z)/(z^2-1)$

Tags: laurent-series

I've come across a problem in my review that has me a little stuck. The question is as follows.

Determine the Laurent Series of the function $$\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}$$ in the domain $|z+1|>2$ centered at $z_0=-1$

Now with this problem, I've tried to rewriting this in numerous different ways, but I can't seem to make much progress on it. I've looked through my book for some key theorem or anything but cannot find one I can apply here.

How would I get started on doing this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$
{e^{z} \over z^2 - 1} = {e^{z} \over (1 + z)(1 - z)}.
$$

The Laurent series you want is:
$$
{1 \over 1 + z} \; (\mbox{the Taylor series of $e^{z}$ at $z_{0} = -1$})
\; (\mbox{the Taylor series of $1/(1-z)$ at $z_{0} = -1$})
$$

Now, the Taylor series of $e^{z}$ at $z_{0} = -1$ is:
$$
e^{z+1 - 1} = {1 \over e} e^{z + 1} = {1 \over e} \sum_{n \geq 0}{1 \over n!} (z + 1)^{n}
$$
The Taylor series of $1 / (1 - z)$ at $z_{0} = -1$ is also not difficult to find.